# Unable to configure azure log alerts on ContainerLog KQL query's aggregated field

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I'm trying to set up an Azure alert rule on a kusto query below:

```
ContainerLog
| parse-where LogEntry with *  '//example.output ' Total:decimal  ' ' Used:decimal ' ' 
| summarize avg_capacity=sum(Used)/sum(Total)*100 by TimeGenerated
```

The query works but when I tried to configure the alert **measurement** it does not pop out the calculated column which is **[avg_capacity]** as in the above query - see screenshot below

[image]

I tried some example Kusto queries that are querying against **Perf** table on Microsoft documentation and it worked fine, not sure what's the problem here,**ContainerLog** as a source table or 'parse-where' operator or?

Basically, I just want an alert rule on the [avg_capacity] field, any help is appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `round()` on the `summarize` value in the sample query posted in question and was able to see **avg_capacity** column in *Measure* dropdown  under *Measurement*.

The issue may be that *Measure* supports decimal values till some decimal places. In your case if the decimal value is above that limit it will not populate the summarize column into the dropdown. Hence by using `round()` we can limit the number of decimal places upto 10 using *Precision*.

**Round():-** It returns the rounded value to the mentioned precision. Default *Precision* is set 0. Please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/roundfunction) to read more about `round()`.

> I have used *Precision* value as 2. It will give us **avg_capacity** value till two decimal places.

**Code**

```
ContainerLog
| parse-where LogEntry with *  '//example.output ' Total:decimal  ' ' Used:decimal ' ' 
| summarize avg_capacity = round(sum(Used)/sum(Total)*100,2) by TimeGenerated
```

**Result**

[image]